# Github - lock Travis config - prevent collaborator from changing it

Tags: github, travis-ci

We're using GitHub and Travis in our organization. The branches are protected, and require Travis build to pass, then are merged automatically.

The problem is that, well, sometimes contributors decide that the best way to fix the build (testing) process is...  ...to remove the tests from the .travis.yml! Yey.

Are there any mechanisms I could use to prevent one file on the branch the user have full access to from being overwritten? Or make .travis use the config from outside of the branch that is being built?

Comment: This is a *cultural* problem, don't patch over it with technology. Do contributors not value the tests? Why not - are they flaky? Are there bugs despite them? Do they make it *harder* to add features and refactor. These are all test smells, and preventing editing the Travis config won't fix them.

Comment: Usually this is solved with code review, which is a good practice anyway.  There are many unacceptable types of code (disabling tests, malicious code, slow code) that you'd want to catch with a code review, and this is just one of them.

Comment: I agree. This could be a serious problem. What if somebody were to fork one of my open-source repos, make massive changes to the travis.yml file and then issue a pull request. Wouldn't they be able to cause a lot of destruction to my open-source repo, since it would have the ability to push to github, deploy to github pages, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Assign a code owner to the .travis.yml file. PRs changing Travis configuration will not be mergeable without the code owner's approval

If you still want to ensure that collaborators get an approval on Travis changes and push new changes before merging, you should enable stale review dismissal